# Fish In The Fish Bowl

Tags: logical-deduction

> There are $x$ fish in a fish tank.
>
> They get fed the same fish food every day. They have varying opinions on the food.
>
> One fish says he only likes fish food that starts with the letter **A**.
>
> Another says he only likes fish food that **ends** with a **vowel.**
>
> Yet another says he doesn't like food that those terrible humans would eat.
>
> Finally, one says he only eats green substances.
>
> The rest are too stubborn to say anything.

Can you figure out what food they all like?

**Note**- The food name doesn't really relate to any *real* fish food names and companies. Answer has to fit all requirements.

Comment: Okay, this is probably too broad. Race to find the craziest answer before it gets closed.

Comment: *"Can you figure out what food they get fed and who likes that certain food?"* - You didn't say the name has to match all of them, we just have to figure out who likes it or not. So the answer could be any food.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, hey, the requirements have changed...

Now they get fed

> ALGAE.

They like it because

> It starts with an A, it ends with a vowel (E), it's green, and it's definitely not human food.

---

Do they get fed...

> FOOD?

If they do...

> Everyone likes it. Jim likes it because it starts with 'F', Joe likes it because it ends with a 'D', Bob likes it because it's only one word, and Bill likes it because it has an 'O' in it.

Comment: Ah you beat me....

Answer (score 1):

I think their daily meal is

> FLOUR

Why? Because...

> Jim is happy because it starts with an F. Joe is satisfied because it ends in a consonant. Bob won't complain because it has a one word name. Bill loves it because it has an O in the name.

Answer (score 1):

How about

> Foolish Fishy Feed?

It satisfies all conditions:

> 1. It starts with F
>  2. Ends with consonant D
>  3. It doesn't have two words it it... It has three!
>  4. It has O in it

Comment: Haha yeah my question was way too broad